# What 3D modelling services could I use to create custom LEGO pieces?

Tags: technic, software, 3d-printing

I want to create some custom LEGO Technic pieces, but I can't seem to find any software that is good at making it. I have tried using Blender, but it is hard to create holes.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I've used Blender for making parts to print (as well as Lego parts). The easiest way I've found to make holes is using 'boolean' object modifier (under the 'spanner' icon). Using the 'difference' operation you can create a hole in the shape of another object. It is a little flaky when the two object share faces/edges/vertices, but otherwise reliable.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried creating my own parts. However, I've seen that [Bricklink's PartDesigner](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/partdesigner.page) is quite popular in the community.  It looks like the creation process is quite streamlined, you can edit the connectivity info of each piece, and it plays very nice with [Bricklink's Studio](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/download.page).

Comment: its good at creating classic and studfull pieces, but its bad, I mean really bad at creating studless pieces

Comment: @vanderrich Can you please describe the problems you are facing? That would help others suggest an alternative that addresses those specific points.

Comment: Bricklink's PartDesigner is good for use cases like creating custom printed minifigs or bricks, but the options are pretty limited if you want to create a new shape.  They're still labeling this "Beta" so maybe it will become usable for more use cases in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry you've been frustrated with Blender.  It is complicated and not as intuitive as it could be, but the alternatives are vastly more expensive for slightly better UX.  3D modeling is a lot of learning, regardless of the tool.  Blender seems to be the best free general 3D modeling package available.  There are tons of tutorials out there and [Blender.SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) for specific questions.

You might find working with Blender is easier if you have exported parts from something LEGO-compatible like [Mecabricks](https://www.mecabricks.com/ru/forum/topic/24).  Export a few Technics bricks and beams and hopefully you can figure out how to cut and paste the sections you need.  Mecabricks also exports STL, OBJ, and DAE files if you want to work with the proprietary 3d modeling packages.

Or you may find it easier to do the bulk of your modeling in Mecabricks and then make a few customizations in Blender.